# Finding out the Potential difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> *Find the potential inside and outside a uniformly charged solid sphere whose radius is $R$ and whose total charge is $q$. Use infinity as your reference point. Compute the gradient of $V$ in each region, and check that it yields the correct result.*

The above one is a question cropped from Griffiths page no 82.

When I try to solve the problem they used  a potential equation inside the sphere

[image]

My problem is in the right part. Why do we need to consider the next part? we have been asked to solve  potential inside a charged sphere. so can't I use only the limit  $\infty $ to $ R$?

I am saying this because, i have considered the infinity as the reference point and R as the point where I will find the potential.

> Is it because we need to add the potential outside of the sphere and inside?

Comment: Yes. If you know the potential on the sphere surface with radius $R$ already from the calculation of the potential outside the sphere you can start the integration for the inside potential at this surface.

Comment: In your question, there is a block quote which says that in the given question you have to find the potential in each region (i.e. Inside, Outside and on the surface of the sphere). Hence you'll have to make three different cases for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering $R$ as the radius of the sphere, The work done in taking a point charge from $\infty$ to $r(0\le r\le R)$ will involve moving the charge through the field outside the sphere and also indside from $R$ to $r$ (**Note that is a solid sphere and field will also be present inside it**).